# Node unpublishes and loses values after edit

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a problem with a node.

I added fields to its node type and edited a node. After saving it, it unpublished AND lost values of its boolean fields. No matter how much I try to edit it again, it is never saved.

What is the problem here?

Comment: How did you add your fields to the content type? By code or in the UI? What fields? Please update your question.

Comment: Hi there, I added the fields normally via drupal backend. Nothing was custom coded. I kinda fixed the problem by resorting the fields in the form via drupal backend, but its still automatically unpublished, when I edit the node.